# Groovy: How do you initialise and compare date/time values from different timezones?

Tags: datetime, groovy

I need to standardise and compare **date/time fields that are in differnt timezones**. eg How do you find the time difference between the following two times?...

```
"18-05-2012 09:29:41 +0800"
"18-05-2012 09:29:21 +0900"
```

What's the best way to initialise standard varaibles with the date/time? 
The output needs to display the difference and normalised data in a timezone (eg +0100) that is different to the incoming values and different to the local environment.

Expected Output:

```
18-05-2012 02:29:41 +0100 
18-05-2012 01:29:21 +0100
Difference: 01:00:20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, use the JodaTime package

```
@Grab( 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1' )
import org.joda.time.*
import org.joda.time.format.*

String a = "18-05-2012 09:29:41 +0800"
String b = "18-05-2012 09:29:21 +0900"

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" );

def start = dtf.parseDateTime( a )
def end = dtf.parseDateTime( b )

assert 1 == Hours.hoursBetween( end, start ).hours
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def dates = ["18-05-2012 09:29:41 +0800",
 "18-05-2012 09:29:21 +0900"].collect{
   new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(it)
}
def dayDiffFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
dayDiffFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
println dates[0]
println dates[1]
println "Difference "+dayDiffFormatter.format(new Date(dates[0].time-dates[1].time))
```

wow. doesn't look readable, does it?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

1. Groovy/Java Date objects are stored as the number of milliseconds after
   1970 and so do not contain any timezone information directly
2. Use **Date.parse** method to initialise the new date to the specified format
3. Use **SimpleDateFormat** class to specify the required output format
4. Use **SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone** to specifiy the timezone of the output
   data
5. By using European/London timezone rather than GMT it will
   automatically adjusts for day light savings time
6. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for a full list of the options for date time patterns

-

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.text.DateFormat

//Initialise the dates by parsing to the specified format
Date timeDate1 = new Date().parse("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z","18-05-2012 09:29:41 +0800")
Date timeDate2 = new Date().parse("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z","18-05-2012 09:29:21 +0900")

DateFormat yearTimeformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
DateFormat dayDifferenceFormatter= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")  //All times differences will be less than a day

// The output should contain the format in UK time (including day light savings if necessary)
yearTimeformatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"))

// Set to UTC. This is to store only the difference so we don't want the formatter making further adjustments
dayDifferenceFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

// Calculate difference by first converting to the number of milliseconds
msDiff = timeDate1.getTime() - timeDate2.getTime()
Date differenceDate = new Date(msDiff)

println yearTimeformatter.format(timeDate1)
println yearTimeformatter.format(timeDate2)
println "Difference " + dayDifferenceFormatter.format(differenceDate)
```

Comment: Date.parse() is deprecated. Use SimpleDateFormat.parse() instead.

Comment: The Java method `Date.parse()` is deprecated.  However, the groovy GDK `Date.parse()` with two arguments (used here) is not.